# SQL Stored Procedure: Reordering rows after delete

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2012

In my database I have three tables as follows:

- `Tasks (TaskID, TaskName, TaskDescription)`
- `TaskDetails (TaskID, subTaskPosition, SubTaskID)`
- `Subtasks (SubTaskID, Description)`

I am trying to write a `Stored Procedure` to delete a `SubTask` completely and then re-order the other `SubTasks` for a `Task`.

Things to note:

- `TaskDetails` links `Tasks` to the constituent `SubTasks`.
- A `SubTask` may be referenced in a number of different Tasks.
- A `Task` should be made up of an ordered list of `SubTasks`... i.e. 1,2,3,4 NOT 1,3,4,5.

It is fairly easy to delete a `SubTask` and its links to a `Task` as follows:

- `DELETE FROM TaskDetails WHERE SubTaskID = @subTaskID`
- `DELETE FROM SubTasks WHERE SubTaskID = @subTaskID`

However, I cannot fathom how to re-order the other `SubTasks` in the `TaskDetails` table once the initial `SubTask` has been deleted. In English, I need to do the following - "For all the Tasks that have just had a `SubTask` deleted from it, subtract 1 from all of the `subTaskPosition` fields that occur after where the deleted row used to be".

Any help or pointers appreciated...

Gordon

Comment: What SQL type is this for?  Oracle, MS SQL Server? DB2? MySql?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said - MS SQL Server (2012) - although it'll also need to run on Azure SQL too! Thanks for the response below - I will try it out later and let you know how I get on. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll have to do an update for each task. This would do the trick (syntax is for SQL Server):

```
DECLARE @TaskID int
DECLARE @SubTaskPosition int

DECLARE curSubTaskPositionUpdate cursor fast_forward
FOR 
    SELECT TaskID, SubTaskPosition
    FROM TaskDetails 
    WHERE SubTaskID = @SubTaskID
OPEN curSubTaskPositionUpdate
FETCH NEXT FROM curSubTaskPositionUpdate INTO @TaskID, @SubTaskPosition
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN   
        UPDATE TaskDetails
        SET SubTaskPosition = SubTaskPosition - 1
        WHERE TaskID = @TaskID
        AND SubTaskPosition > @SubTaskPosition

        FETCH NEXT FROM curSubTaskPositionUpdate INTO @TaskID, @SubTaskPosition
    END
CLOSE curSubTaskPositionUpdate
DEALLOCATE curSubTaskPositionUpdate
```

Note you do that before deleting from TaskDetails... and you probably want to wrap everything in a transaction.

Gordon Edit - I had to include my delete code within the update code to make this work, otherwise either (a) the delete occurred first and "where subtaskID = @subtaskID" returned nothing OR (b) I did the delete after the re-ordering and the re-order (correctly!) had no effect.

```
DECLARE @TaskID uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @SubTaskPosition int 

DECLARE curSubTaskPositionUpdate cursor fast_forward 
FOR  
    SELECT TaskID, SubTaskPosition 
    FROM TaskDetails  
    WHERE SubTaskID = @subTaskID 
OPEN curSubTaskPositionUpdate 
FETCH NEXT FROM curSubTaskPositionUpdate INTO @TaskID, @SubTaskPosition 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
   BEGIN    
-- Delete the subTask
DELETE FROM TaskDetails
WHERE TaskID = @TaskID
AND SubTaskPosition = @SubTaskPosition 

-- Update the other subTasks
        UPDATE TaskDetails
        SET SubTaskPosition = SubTaskPosition - 1
        WHERE TaskID = @TaskID
        AND SubTaskPosition > @SubTaskPosition

        FETCH NEXT FROM curSubTaskPositionUpdate INTO @TaskID, @SubTaskPosition
    END
CLOSE curSubTaskPositionUpdate
DEALLOCATE curSubTaskPositionUpdate
```

Comment: Thanks James, with a few minor tweaks I managed to get this working - although Barry's code may be more efficient if I can tweak that!

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
UPDATE  TaskDetails
SET     subTaskPosition = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TaskID  ORDER BY subTaskPosition) 
WHERE   TaskID IN(  SELECT  s.TaskID 
                    FROM    TaskDetails s 
                    WHERE   SubTaskID = @subTaskID)
```

No loops necessary...  Note that this also works for case where multiple subtasks are missing or have already been deleted for the same task.

---

OK, here's the corrected version for SQL Server:

```
;WITH
  cteRows As
(
    SELECT  *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TaskID  ORDER BY subTaskPosition) As NewPosition
    FROM    TaskDetails
)
UPDATE  cteRows
SET     subTaskPosition = NewPosition
WHERE   TaskID IN(  SELECT  s.TaskID 
                    FROM    TaskDetails s 
                    WHERE   SubTaskID = @subTaskID)
```

Sorry for the delay ...

Comment: I like it! It should be noted that it might update rows which do not need to be updated. Also I think it should be "WHERE TaskID IN (".

Comment: This is a value subquery, it's equally valid with IN or EXISTS subqueries (and they are usually (but not always) interchangeable)

Comment: Hi Barry, thanks very much for your help with this. This may be down to the fact I didn't specify I was using SQL Server, but I get an error reading "Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.". Any ideas?

Comment: Many thanks Barry - this seemingly simple job though is actually quite taxing. Unfortunately your code doesn't work in my application. I *think* the reason for it is that because I have to delete the subTask from the TaskDetails table BEFORE your re-order code, your "WHERE SubTaskID = @subTaskID" fails to find anything. I have managed to get a version of James's code below working if you'd like to take a look - although I believe you almost have a more elegant solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

First get the position of the sub rask, delete, and update the records:

```
declare @pos int
select @pos = subTaskPosition from TaskDetails where SubTaskID = @subTaskID
delete ...
delete ...
update TaskDetails set subTaskPosition = subTaskPosition + 1 where SubTaskID = @subTaskID and subTaskPosition > @pos
```